# How can I update an existing table with an array of objects?

Tags: sql, postgresql

When the user clicks on another user, a new item is created in the chats table, with a sender and receiver id but an empty chat message.

when the user sends a message, depending on who he sends it to, the item in the chat table will be updated with the sent message.

```
the message object looks like this [{message: "abc", sender: "person", 
reciever:"person2"}] // there will be multiple object inside the arr
```

at the moment this is how I my table look:

```
chats (sender_id, reciever_id, messages jsonb[])
```

and this is the query I'm sending

```
UPDATE chats SET 
messages = '[
  { message: 'hi', sender: 'test', reciever: null },
  { message: 'hello', sender: 'test', reciever: null }
]' WHERE 
sender_id = 47 AND 
reciever_id = 43
```

This is causing errors, and not updating the table. The error doesn't tell me much, but I think it's due to the fact that my object is not in json format(strings on the keys)

so what data type can I use, to allow me to update my messages column using MY format.

Comment: What error is this causing?

Comment: You're using single quotes to define your string. And you're using single quotes also inside your text as a part of it. This is the issue. The content of the messages should be delimited by double quotes as well as their corresponding key, if you don't want to bump into that problem.

Comment: Also don't use strings to store json values. Use the JSON datatype.

Comment: I don't quite understand, I changed it to this and I'm still getting an error:

UPDATE chats SET 
messages = [
  { message: 'hi', sender: 'test', reciever: null },
  { message: 'hello', sender: 'test', reciever: null }
] WHERE 
sender_id = 47 AND 
reciever_id = 43

error is caused by the [

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use double quotes for json.

your data also doesn't need an jsonb array, so i removed it

```
CREATE TABLE chats (sender_id int, reciever_id int, messages jsonb)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO chats VALUES (47,43, NULL)
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
UPDATE chats SET 
messages = '[
  { "message": "hi", "sender": "test", "reciever": null },
  { "message": "hello", "sender": "test", "reciever": null }
]' WHERE 
sender_id = 47 AND 
reciever_id = 43
```

> ```
> UPDATE 1
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM chats
```

| sender_id | reciever_id | messages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 47 | 43 | [{"sender": "test", "message": "hi", "reciever": null}, {"sender": "test", "message": "hello", "reciever": null}] |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q_7DESAX)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you have a good tutorial/doc for working with json in databases. It's pretty annoying, even chatGPT couldn't solve simple questions. Thanks again.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) is really your best friend here. When you have a json related problem, try going through the available functions description and provided examples. @Muath_01

Comment: the tutorials and webpage only cover the basics, a search engine yields often solutions like you will find here in Stackoverflow or other sides, but if you have questions ask them freely